# Serve static folder with authentication in the asp net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using asp net core 2.0.5 with MVC and want to serve a static folder outside of `wwwroot`.

My input files would look like below.

```
wwwroot
staticfolder
    10
        index.html
        image1.png
        image2.png
        sub-folder
            image3.jpg
```

The `index.html` is generated by other program. All images are used in the index.html.

We want to server in after checking the authentication, i.e. users can view `index.html` through a path `api/flight/10/index.html`. But I need to check the user permission to access resource `flight 10`.

I understand `Physicalfile` can be used to serve a static file (e.g. *.png) outside wwwroot, and also configure `app.UseStaticFiles` to serve folders and files in the startup.cs.

Some pseudo codes for a minimum example.

```
[Route("api/flight/{flight}/index.html")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetImageThumbnail(
    [FromRoute] int flight)
{
    // Check permission
    List<Flight> data = _context
        .Flight(id: flight)
        .ToList();

    if (data.Count() == 0)
    {
        return NotFound("No permission.");
    }

    // data[0].BaseFolder is a folder outside wwwroot
    string filename = data[0].BaseFolder + "/index.html";
    // Return the content for index.html
    ...
}
```

So my question is how should I server a folder mixed with html and images using the similar method above.

Comment: Did I understand right that you want that flight check for a specific folder within `wwwroot`?

Comment: No, outside wwwroot folder

Comment: Can you clarify how should desired end result look like, please - what's the input and what's output.

Comment: Thanks. i will try my best to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to achieve my target. Post here in case others have the same problem.

The key thing is to set Route using `{*file}` which will match any string at the end.

```
[Route("api/flight/{flight}/{*file}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetImageThumbnail([FromRoute]int flight, 
    [FromRoute] string file)
{

    // Check permission
    List<Flight> data = _context
    .Flight(id: flight)
    .ToList();

    if (data.Count() == 0)
    {
    return NotFound("No permission.");
    }
    string filename = Path.Combine(data[0].BaseFolder, file);
    var provider = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

    string minetype = "";
    provider.TryGetContentType(filename, out minetype);
    return PhysicalFile(filename, minetype);
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to find any other elegant method to achieve it?

Comment: No other methods until now